# Jstree, check if drop is bellow, inside or above the node

Tags: javascript, jstree, jstree-dnd

I already know how to get the ID from the dragged node and from the target node. However I need to know if that drop was inside the node bellow or above. How can I do that?

```
divTree.jstree({
    'core': {
        'check_callback': true,
        'data': data,
        'themes': {
            'icons': hasIcons,
            'dots': hasDots
        }
    },
    'plugins': ['themes', 'ui', 'search', 'contextmenu','dnd'],
    'search': {
        'case_sensitive': false,
        'show_only_matches': true
    },
    'contextmenu': {
        'items': contextMenu != null ? contextMenu : ''
    }
})
```

**This is my JStree**

```
$(document).on("dnd_stop.vakata", eventDrop);
```

**This is How I call the drop event**

```
const eventDrop = (data) => {
    let elementID = data.data.nodes[0]
    let targetID = data.event.target.parentNode.id;
}
```

**And this is where I get th enodes ID**

I would like to find something like:

```
const eventDrop = (data) => {
let elementID = data.data.nodes[0]
let targetID = data.event.target.parentNode.id;
let elementPosition = data.event.indexPos; (Where it could say if its inside, bellow, our above)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after I took a deeper look inside the Jstree code I think I found the answer.
So basically what I did is every time the mouse moves inside the tree, checks if the position of the mouse towards the element that is hover (or closest) is bellow, above or inside.

**I changed my event to this:**

```
 const evt_adminmodules_areaTree_OnDrop = (e, data) => {
    if (data.event.type == 'mouseup') {
        let elementID = data.data.nodes[0]
        let targetID = data.event.target.parentNode.id;
    }
    else if (data.event.type == 'mousemove') {
        let ref = $(data.event.target).closest('.jstree-anchor');
        let off = ref.offset();
        if (off) {
            let rel = data.event.pageY - off.top;
            let h = ref.outerHeight();
            if (rel < h / 3) _dropPosition = 'up';
            else if (rel > h - h / 3) _dropPosition = 'bot';
            else _dropPosition = 'mid';
        }
    }
}
```

At least for this solved the problem :D!
Thank you